# What server operating system should I use for a virtual TFS build server?

Tags: team-foundation-server

I have the task of setting up a TFS build server which will consist of 1 controller and 1 agent for TFS / Visual Studio 2013.

I have a choice of server operating systems, since this will be a virtual server it will also be competing for server resources.

I'm inclined to install Windows Server 2008 R2, however I thought I would ask you guru's because I want the best possible install with the least amount of problems.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of TFS are you installing? This is pretty much the main factor in decidng your OS version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578592.aspx) is clear about supported OS. I have no issue with 2012 nor with 2012 R2 and I see no reason to go with 2008 R2 which will go out of mainstream support in 6 months ([MS lifecycle](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?c2=1163)).

So, if you are installing recent version of Visual Studio/TFS, use a recent version of Windows Server.

Comment: What will your developers build? Win8 apps require the build server to be installed on Win8 machine. [This topic][1] mentions this requirement with a link to more information. Otherwise, I would echo what Giulio said.

Comment: I lost my comment when they voted this question down.